# Sorting strings in a linked list

Tags: c++, string, sorting, linked-list

The function works quite ok but the problem comes in when I insert the same surname more than once. Please help, it's my school project.

```
void sortList(node*head)
{
    node*temp2;
    node*temp3;
    string tmp, tmp1, tmp2;
    unsigned long long tmp3;
    unsigned long long num;

    for(temp2= head; temp2 != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next)
    {
        for(temp3 = temp2-> next; temp3 != NULL; temp3 = temp3 ->next)
        {
            if(temp2 ->surname > temp3 ->surname)
            {
                tmp  = temp2 ->surname;
                tmp1 = temp2 ->name;
                tmp2 = temp2 ->date;
                tmp3 = temp2 ->num;
                temp2 ->name = temp3 ->surname;
                temp2 ->surname = temp3 ->name;
                temp2 ->date = temp3 -> date;
                temp2 ->num  = temp3 -> num;
                temp3 ->surname = tmp;
                temp3 ->name = tmp1;
                temp3 ->date = tmp2;
                temp3 ->num  = tmp3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use `std::swap` (or your own `swap` if you can't use it) to clean the code.

Comment: You should use sensible, descriptive variable names, rather than `tmp`, `tmp1`, `tmp2`, `tmp3`, `temp2` and `temp3`.

Comment: I see no reason to suppose that. The OP has used std::string it seems in his function body so there's no reason to believe that he didn't previously.

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple bug in the swapping part of your code:

```
// temp2->name = temp3->surname;
// temp2->surname = temp3->name;

// should be:
temp2->name = temp3->name;
temp2->surname = temp3->surname;
```

Like others already noted, the code could be much cleaner, which would also help to avoid such errors (they would be easier to spot at least).

> how do I make sure that if they have the same surname then the precedence of their firsnames should be used to determine their order? –  Jdons

In this case, i suggest to use a helper function for determining the order of two nodes:

```
bool isLessThan(node* lhs, node* rhs)
{
    if (lhs->surname == rhs->surname)
    {
        // if they have the same surname,
        // use the firstname
        return lhs->name < rhs->name;
    }
    else
    {
        // else use surname
        return lhs->surname < rhs->surname;
    }
}
```

(This is not the most efficient way and one could use operator< instead, but I wanted to keep things simple)

Usage in your original code:

```
for(temp2= head; temp2 != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next)
{
    for(temp3 = temp2-> next; temp3 != NULL; temp3 = temp3 ->next)
    {
        if(!isLessThan(temp2, temp3))
        {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've corrected and working alright, thanks but just one more thing, how do I make sure that if they have the same surname then the precedence of their firsnames should be used to determine their order?

Comment: (Answered you followup question in a edit to the answer post)

Answer (score -2):

First of all I would make the code more readable by using more descriptive variables.
Secondly I would use STL functions and containers to solve this bubble sort algorithm.

Assuming you have to use your own implementation, I would suggest to review the string::operator>(...) function that you are using here. You can post it here if you want so we can review it.

Hope this helps.

Carles.